# Multiple functions - Second Function not working

Tags: javascript, html

The first Prompt is working. The second is not working. the second function supposed to check if email contains @

I tried to switch the email function place

```
<body onload="check_user_age(); check_email" style="position:absolute">
    <h1>Spiritueux Wines and Liquors</h1>
    <script>
        function check_user_age() {
            if (age_of_user() < 18)
                alert("You are too young to buy alcohol.");
        }

        function age_of_user() {
            var age = prompt("What is your age?");
            return age;
        }


        function check_email() {
            if (email.includes("@"));
            alert("Your email is correct");
        }

        function email_of_user() {
            var email = prompt("what is your email");
            return email;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Well they are coded differently and you do not call `check_email`

Comment: There's a stray semi-colon at the end of the `if` statement, which causes the `body` of the `if` to be empty.

Answer (score 3):

First you do not call the method

```
onload="check_user_age(); check_email"
                                   ^^^ not executed
```

Second you have a semicolon after the if

```
if (email.includes("@"));
                       ^^^
```

Third, email is not defined

```
if (email.includes("@"));
    ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in the **onload** event, you are not calling the function. Second, in **check_email()**, you are giving semicolon which is making **if** body empty. Third, you are checking the condition with undefined variable. Because of these reasons, you are not getting output. You can write like these:

```js
function check_user_age() {
  if (age_of_user() < 18)
    alert("You are too young to buy alcohol.")
  else
    alert('Welcome to Spiritueux Wines and Liquors')
}
function age_of_user() {
  var age = prompt("What is your age?");
  return age;
}
function check_email() {
  if (email_of_user().includes("@"))
    alert("Your email is correct");
  else
    alert('Your email is incorrect')
}

function email_of_user() {
  var email = prompt("what is your email");
  return email;
}
```

```html
<body onload="check_user_age(); check_email()" style="position:absolute">
    <h1>Spiritueux Wines and Liquors</h1>
  </body>
```